# Excel - How get everything to the left of the second to last instance of a character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I return everything to the left of the second to last occurrence of a character? In this case, the character is "-"
For example:

1. "hello-baby-123-sun" I need to return "hello-baby"
2. "hello-baby-123-sun-shine-123", I need to return "hello-baby-123-sun"

Thanks!

I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `TEXTBEFORE()` function with the instance being `-2`

[image]

---

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A2,"-",-2)
```

---

Alternatively, adding an error control is necessary:

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A2,"-",-2),A1:A2)
```

---

For Older Versions, one can try one of the followings:

• Using `LEFT()` & `FIND()`

```
=IFERROR(
 LEFT(A1,
 FIND("|",
 SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","|",
 LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",))-1))-1),A1)
```

---

• Or Using `FILTERXML()`<sup>╪</sup> as mentioned in comments by **@Harun24hr**:

```
=IFERROR(
 INDEX(
 FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","</b><b>",
 LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",))-1)&"</b></m>","//b"),1),A1)
```

---

<sup>╪ Note: `FILTERXML()` is available from `Excel 2013+` onwards as well as it is not applicable in `Excel For The Web` and `Excel For MAC`. `TEXTBEFORE()` works with `MS365` Exclusively.</sup>

---

<sup>One can learn more on `FILTERXML()` from the following link, nice article by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, **[Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)**</sup>

Comment: Perfect use of `TEXTBEFORE()`. For older versions `FILTERXML()` may work.